# bake vertex color to texture with python

Tags: python

I'm trying a find a way to bake existent vertex color of an object to texture file with python code.

can anyone help me?

EDIT:
I found this:

`Ob = context.active_object
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
UVLayer = Ob.data.uv_textures.new(name='MathTextureUV') if 'MathTextureUV' not in Ob.data.uv_textures.keys() else Ob.data.uv_textures['MathTextureUV']
UVLayer.active = UVLayer.active_render = True
bpy.ops.uv.unwrap()
Image = D.images.new('MathTextureImage', self.texture_size, self.texture_size)
for uv in UVLayer.data:
     uv.image = Image
VLayer = Ob.data.vertex_colors.new(name='MathTextureVColor') if 'MathTextureVColor' not in Ob.data.vertex_colors.keys() else Ob.data.vertex_colors['MathTextureVColor']
VLayer.active = VLayer.active_render = True
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='VERTEX_PAINT')
   -- boring stuff
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
context.scene.render.bake_type = 'VERTEX_COLORS'
bpy.ops.object.bake_image()`

here: https://blenderartists.org/t/baking-textures-with-python/610553

but this not exactly what I need because I already have UV and vertex color in my model.